# Customize ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have to customize ASP.NET Identity entities.

I have these classes:

```
<!-- language: c# -->

public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser<string, ApplicationLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationClaim> {}

public class: UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationClaim> {}

public class ApplicationUserManager: UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {}
}
```

How can I create instance of `IUserStore<ApplicationUser>` for DI in this case?

---

I can't derive my DbContex from IdentityDbContext because of using unit of work repository.
I have found similar question [here](http://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/discussions/544013).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create some another classes and interfaces:

```
public interface IApplicationUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser, string>
{

}

public class ApplicationUserStore :
    UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>,
    IApplicationUserStore
{
    public ApplicationUserStore()
        : base(new ApplicationDbContext())
    {

    }

    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

And create class ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("AuthenticationConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    ...
}
```

then from your ApplicationUserManager you would be able to call

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

And this is the complete class ApplicationUserManager that receives IApplicationUserStore in the constructor:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, Guid>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IApplicationUserStore store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>())) { PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher() };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = false,
            };

            return manager;
        }
    }
```